# Overriding instance method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

While overriding some assignment methods, I discovered that if I use the implicit receiver in the field_two method, the first overridden method, field_one, doesn't get called.  Instead, the default 'field_one=' seems to be called.

```
#controller
def do_something
  @something=Something.first
  @something.field_two="some_value"
end

class Something<ActiveRecord::Base

def field_one=(value)
  puts "hi"
  write_attribute(:field_g_five,value)
end


def field_two=(value)
  field_one="whatever"
  write_attribute(:field_g_one,value)
end

end
```

However, if I change the receiver to be explicit, my overridden method gets called:

```
def field_two=(value)
  self.field_one="whatever"
  write_attribute(:field_g_one,value)
end
```

What is going on here?

Comment: do you have another variable in the calling scope named for field_one ?

Comment: Did my edit answer your question?  I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: @TarynEast Doesn't matter. He's creating one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `field_one` isn't getting called, you're setting a local variable called `field_one` inside the method.

If you want to make it explicit that you want to call the `field_one` method inside that class, you must prefix it with `self`.