# Overriding Instance Method in Rails Library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, actionmailer, instance-method

This seems like a monkey patch.  How can I improve it?

Trying to override the `deliver_now` instance method from the ActionMailer::MessageDelivery class.  The below code works.

However, is there a way I can achieve this more elegantly say through class inheritance or some other way?  The end code is used in a custom ActionMailer mailer.

```
module MyModule
  class Ses 

    ActionMailer::MessageDelivery.class_eval do
      def deliver_now!
        puts self.to
        puts self.subject
      end
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

Note:  I've seen these similar questions [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502606/overriding-instance-method-in-rails) & [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715/why-do-ruby-setters-need-self-qualification-within-the-class) but they do not address this issue.

Comment: There are other ways to set the email header fields (to/from/subject). If this is the only reason you're overriding the method, I would look at those other ways to do it. I don't have a list handy, but you can set them on each method, at the class level, and even in the config files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look into Ruby's [refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html)

An example refinement:

```
module MyMessageRefinement
  refine(ActionMailer::MessageDelivery) do
    def deliver_now!
      puts self.to
      puts self.subject
    end
  end    
end
```

Then in your class:

```
module MyModule
  class Ses 
    using MyMessageRefinement
  end
end
```